# What is the latest release of quickcheck for R?

Tags: r, quickcheck

What is the latest release of quickcheck for R? If this answer became outdated, how would I find out, by hand or from within a program?

Answer (score 0):

As of this writing, it's 3.2.0. 
To find the most up-to-date answer, either check [here](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/quickcheck/releases) or use the following R code:

```
   library(httr)
   library(rjson)
   fromJSON(
     content(
       GET("https://api.github.com/repos/RevolutionAnalytics/quickcheck/releases"),
      "text"))[[1]]$tag_name
```